# move_uploaded_file returns an error code of 0

Tags: php

Please see code snippet at the end of this post...

I consistently get back an error code of 0 when attempting to use `move_uploaded_file` to move a tmp file into another directory.  I've confirmed that the directory exists and the permissions are set to 775 on it.  I've also checked with the server admin and he says he's not seeing any errors in the error log that would explain the issue I'm having.

How do I get around an error code of 0 when using `move_uploaded_file`?

```
$audio_dir  = "/mbc/data/audio/";

if (isset($_POST['upload_audio'])) {

    $title      = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['audio_title']);
    $category   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['audio_category']);
    $audio_name = basename($_FILES['audio_file']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $audio_dir.$audio_name;

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM media where path = '" . $audio_name . "'");
    $result = mysql_result($query, 0, 0);

    if (($title == '') || ($title == NULL) ||
        ($category == '') || ($category == NULL) ||
        ($audio_name == '') || ($audio_name == NULL)) {
        echo "<span class='error'>Title, Category and Audio file are required fields</span>";                            
    } else if ($result > 0) {
    echo "<span class='error'>Media $audio_name already exists - please upload with a different name</span>";                               
    } else if (ctype_alpha($category) === false) {
        echo "<span class='error'>Category can only have letters (no spaces, commas, numbers, etc...)</span>";              
    } else if (ctype_alnum(substr($audio_name, 0, strpos($audio_name, '.'))) === false) {
    echo "<span class='error'>Bad filename - $audio_name - can only contain letters and numbers (i.e. 'HowGreatThouArt.mp3')</span>";
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['audio_file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            $queryInsertAudio = "insert into media (title, path, category ) values ('{$title}','{$audio_name}','{$category}')";
            $result = mysql_query($queryInsertAudio);
            if ($result) {
                echo "<span class='success'>AUDIO $audio_name UPLOADED SUCCESSFULLY</span>";
            } else {
                echo "<span class='error'>FAILED TO INSERT RECORD FOR $audio_name - PLEASE CONTACT ADMINISTRATOR</span>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<span class='error'>FAILED TO UPLOAD AUDIO $audio_name - PLEASE CONTACT ADMINISTRATOR<br />" . 
                 "ERROR CODE = " . $_FILES['audio_file']['error'] . "<br />" . 
                 "Temp filename=" . $_FILES['audio_file']['tmp_name'] . "<br />" .
                 "Uploadfile=" . $uploadfile . "<br />" .
                 print_r($_FILES) . 
                "</span>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you see the file in the temporary location before you attempt to move it? How big is the file? Have you increased PHPs max upload size?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file` return value is `boolean` where you get that `0`?

Comment: The file is a measly 580kb.  I don't have access to see the file in the tmp directory but I get a filename back successfully when I echo `$_FILES['audio_file']['tmp_name']` so I assume it exists...

Comment: @Vytautas - `$_FILES['audio_file']['error']` is the error code I'm referring to

Comment: then `0` means no error upload was successful http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: @Vytautas - but I'm not seeing my file show up in my upload directory

Comment: if your directory is in other chan apache usergroup that would be www-data I guess you have to set public permisions to 776 not 775. Also make some debug and find exact spot where your code fails what errors does it prints and so on..

Comment: the simplest way you can check if it's a permission issue or not is by temporarily changing permission to directory to 0777. Can you also print the output you get for the last part of the code, i.e. the error span

Comment: You are vulnerable to SQL injection... Also, learn to use mysqli or pdo

Comment: @ColeJohnson - where am I vulnerable?  I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string` on my variables...

Comment: @ZackMacomber `$audio_name = basename($_FILES['audio_file']['name']);` isn't escaped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOPS...it was my `$audio_dir` file path that was off...fixed that up and now I'm able to upload no problem...